# Keep sklearnt model in memory to speed up prediction

Tags: python, python-2.7, scikit-learn

I have trained a SVM model with sklearn, I need to connect this to php. To do this I am using exec command to call in the console the python script, where I load the model with pickle and predict the results. The problem is that loading the model with pickle takes some time (a couple of seconds) and I would like it to be faster. Is there a way of having this model in memory so I don't need to load with pickle every time?

Comment: Use need something like `[Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/)` to expose and API with the model pre-loaded in memory

Comment: Thanks, I took this approach and I was able to solve it.

Answer (score -1):

Can't you store only the parameters of your SVM classifier with `clf.get_params()` instead of the whole object?

Comment: I have the model already trained, I don't need the parameters what I need is the model weights.

Comment: The SVM classifier is not like a neural network, there are no model weights, but rather an hyperplane which separates your data. If you store the coordinates of your hyperplane (which you can get with `get_params()`) then you can create a new SVM classifier with the exact same hyperplane, therefore this new classifier will behave exactly like the previous classifier.

Comment: Thats true! I didn't realize I don't need the object, however the input of the SVM is a vector obtained by a bag of words, for wich I need around 300000 words saved in a dictionary what makes the loading slow. I have solve it by using flask.

Comment: 300k words is **A LOT**. Try reducing the number of features with text mining techniques (removing stop words, stemming...) and maybe even reducing the number of variables with PCA or other tools.

Comment: I have tried, the problem is that the text is multilingual, I need to add words from many languages (like 10 different languages) and I don't have a way of knowing which language they come from.